# File Still Locked Despite putting StreamReader in Using

Tags: c#, file, io, streamreader

My program goes through all files in a folder, reads them, and without altering their information moves them to another location under a different name. However I cannot use the `File.Move` method because I get the following `IOException`:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

This is how I am reading the file and adding all its lines to a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> lines = null;
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default))
    {
        lines = new List<string>();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
```

And this is the function with which I move the file:

```
public static bool ArchiveFile(string filePath, string archiveFolderLocation)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(archiveFolderLocation))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveFolderLocation);
    try
    {
        string timestamp = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss}", DateTime.Now);
        string newFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + " " + timestamp;
        string destination = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", archiveFolderLocation, newFileName, Path.GetExtension(filePath));
        File.Move(filePath, destination);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I thought using the `using` statement is supposed to garbage-collect and release the file after being used. How can I release the file so I can move it and why my file stays locked?

**Solved:**

Got it. Somewhere between these two calls I was opening a `TextReader`object without disposing it.

Comment: how the code snippets are linked?where is it throwing?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh the upper snippet is run first and then comes the `ArchiveFile` method. The Exception occurs in the `File.Move` line of the `ArchiveFile` method.

Comment: are you sure the file is not being used anywhere else? the `using` should work. but the problem is somewhere else

Comment: do you use multi threading to move the files ?. example Parallel or await task?

Comment: Not the issue, but wouldn't `List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.Default).ToList();` work just the same?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary got it. Somewhere between these two calls I was opening a `TextReader` object without disposing it.

Comment: working perfectly fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought using the using statement is supposed to garbage-collect and
>   release the file after being used. How can I release the file so I can
>   move it and why my file stays locked?

Not really. Using statement is nothing but :

```
try { var resource = new SomeResource(); } 

finally { resource.Dispose(); // which is not GC.Collect(); }
```

It works fine so it looks like your file is opened from some other place in your code...

P.S.
By the way you can just do:

`List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines().ToList();`

Answer (score -2):

**You could use:**

```
string dpath = "D:\\Destination\\";
            string spath = "D:\\Source";
            string[] flist = Directory.GetFiles(spath);
            foreach (string item in flist)
            {
                File.Move(item, dpath + new FileInfo(item).Name);
            }
```

**Replace D:\\Source & D:\\Destination\\  with the required source and destination paths, respectively.**

Comment: Why `dynamic flist`? I'd understand `var flist`, but `dymanic` seems inappropriate here, where you're *guaranteed* you'll get a `string[]` and only use it as that.

Comment: yeah you're right. i don't know much of c#. i wrote the program in vb.net. then using the Telerik Code Converter converted it into C#. it converted 'dim' to 'dynamic'. Now fixed.

Comment: If you're unsure of the answer, it might be better suited as a comment, as opposed to an answer.  Telerik's code converter works okay most of the time, but has the tendency to occasionally produce weird or in some cases, completely broken code.

Comment: but i tested this code and it works perfect. test it for yourself if you want